# MySQL: do you explicitly have to say which row must be locked or does INNODB just know it?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I know INNODB has row-level locking. So if I do this:

```
LOCK TABLES users WRITE
SELECT credits FROM users WHERE userid = 1;
UPDATE users SET credits = ([CREDITS] + 100) WHERE userid = 1;
UNLOCK TABLES
```

Is innoDB smart enough to lock only that row for that second, or is there some other step I must take in order to lock only the row? How does innodb know only to lock this one user during my duration? Is it locked at the SELECT already as it should be?

Comment: Is this just an example, or is this the code you are using? To make sure you are doing this right you should probably be better off by either doing a `SELEC .. .FOR UPDATE` in a transaction, or do this in one query like `UPDATE users SET credits = credits + 100 WHERE userid = 1`;. No need to select the credits first, you can use the column in the query itself.

Comment: My concern is concurrency? Will a query like that work 100% concurrently? It really looks like it would.

Comment: Yes. that update query is completely safe, with no other query coming in between. If you have to do something more complicated user a transaction, possibly with a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` like I said. THat's what they're for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need to lock the table on your own if you create the table
with the option Engine = InnoDB a InnoDB monitor will be created.

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The monitor locks the table automatically, but the lock is not for a single row InnoDB will lock the hole table for the operation/transaction.

Maybe the user want only to Read the Table he gets the s lock on the hole table.
Simultaneously a other user can also read the table, but if he wants to delete a row and he requests the x lock he must wait of the other user, until he released his s lock.

#### MYSQL lock type compatibility matrix.

```
    X           IX            S          IS
X   Conflict    Conflict    Conflict    Conflict
IX  Conflict    Compatible  Conflict    Compatible
S   Conflict    Conflict    Compatible  Compatible
IS  Conflict    Compatible  Compatible  Compatible
```

Please read the mysql doc.:

InnoDB monitor - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-monitors.html

InnoDB lock modes - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html